# Changing some part of the question after asking

Tags: feature-request

Sometimes it is like we ask the question and after some answers or comments we notice some of the drawbacks of the question. The feature will let you some part of the question, not the whole question. Yes, we can close the question afterwards, and reask it from scratch with some changes, but it would save a lot of time just implementing the changes in the original question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exit strategies for "chameleon questions"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)

Comment: If a question is unclear people should ask for details or clarification **before** answering (using comments or the close dialog). Questions that are edited to alter their meaning ***and*** **invalidate** an answer ought to be rolled back. --- Editing after comments = good, editing after answers ~= bad.

Comment: Something is missing near *"...will let you some..."*. Do you mean *"...will let you change some..."*?

Comment: A Q&A pair is forever & other people that come after you. You are thinking only of yourself.

Answer (score 6):

The key thing with any changes that you make to your question, after one or more answers have been posted, is that those changes do not invalidate any of the answers.

It is often not easy to do that, so in general, it is better to become good at writing clear and focused questions at the outset.